# как сделать, чтобы idea показывала вместе декомпилированных классов читаемые исходники jdk?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

как сделать, чтобы idea показывала вместе декомпилированных классов читаемые исходники jdk?

Comment: Скачать исходники и показать в настройках JDK где лежат исходники

Comment: На линуксовых машинах в большинстве случаев достаточно установить пакет `*jdk-*-source`

Answer (score 1):

Откройте Project Settings, и посмотрите как добавлены зависимости. Там есть отдельные табины для source'ов и документации. Если речь чисто о JDK классах, то это тоже настраивается в настройках Java SDK.